# FireFox massive slowdown on upgrade to 13.10

Tags: firefox, 13.10

In 13.04 FireFox was working just fine, but after the upgrade, every few minutes, FireFox locks up and eventually changes to that dreaded "grayscale window" for several seconds.

The problem appeared immediately after the upgrade. I'm afraid I don't know which version I had before the upgrade, but now I am running `FireFox 24.0`.

Is this a known bug, or are there any steps I can take to find the root cause?

Comment: Refer to [this][1] .  Debug using Firefox Debugger.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450329/after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-10-firefox-sometimes-crashes-the-computer/477893#477893

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried disabling all my add-ons, and the problem went away. Re-enabling them one at a time, I found that **Ubuntu FireFox Modifications 2.8** was causing the performance issues. *That add-on wasn't installed by me, but must have been added automatically with the upgrade.*

If anyone else runs into the issue, go to the `Tools` menu and click `Add-ons`. Scroll down in the list until you find `Ubuntu FireFox Modifications`, and click the `Disable` button (may require a restart to take effect).

Comment: Originally I didn't think add-ons would be the cause of the issue, as I didn't install any new ones manually after the upgrade, and my existing list of add-ons is already spartan.

Comment: Disabling the Firefox modifications didn't get rid of the problem for me, in fact, it appears as though Firefox is the canary in the mine, it happens elsewhere also but Firefox shows it up quickly likely because I use it a lot.

Comment: I was right on the cusp of moving my Firefox profile onto a USB stick and throwing it into the sea. You've just saved me a USB stick and a long drive. Thank you.